# Filter Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, filter, excel

I have a customer who asked a very difficult requirement and do not know if possible.

It uses excel but all migrated to sharepoint, and there is a filter in excel there is a text field to write and go filtering the filter itself. And he wishes, if possible, put a text field in sharepoint folder.

Filter Excel 2013:

[image]

Filter SharePoint 2013:

[image]

As described above, in excel 2013 there is a text filter, and want to know how to put the same text filter in sharepoint 2013.

thank you.

I speak Portuguese.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way OOTB to have a column filter behave like the one you have in Excel. As you already noticed, the SharePoint filter is an exact-match type of filter.
There is a workaround though, which involves creating a parameter on the XsltListViewWebPart and adding either a text filter webpart or a textbox input control on the same page where the XLVWP lives which will send its value to the aforementioned parameter.

You can find a detailed explanation on [this blog post](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/pages/sharepoint-search-in-xsltlistviewwebpart.aspx)

I'll recap below the basic steps required (the example is for an textbox input control):

1 add an input text box with a 'Search' button on the XLVWP page

2 configure a new ParameterBinding element in the XLVWP, bound to the text box

3 edit the View parameter, adding a where clause to the query:

```
  <Where>
      <Contains>
        <FieldRef Name="Title"/>
        <Value Type="Text">{SearchText}</Value>
      </Contains>
    </Where>
```

There will be some minor glitches left to fix at this point; refer to the provided link for more information